# Character drawing routine doesn't read the bitmap properly

Tags: c, drawing

Here's the bitmap array:

```
unsigned int font[][4] = {
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* NUL */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* SOH */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* STX */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* ETX */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* EOT */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* ENQ */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* ACK */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* BEL */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* BS */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* HT */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* LF */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* VT */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* FF */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* CR */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* SO */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* SI */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* DLE */ 
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* DC1 */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* DC2 */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* DC3 */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* DC4 */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* NAK */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* SYN */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* ETB */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* CAN */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* EM */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* SUB */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* ESC */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* FS */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* GS */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* RS */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* US */
    {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, /* ' ' */
    {0x18, 0x1818, 0x1800, 0x1818}, /* '!' */
    {0x42, 0x4200, 0x0, 0x0} /* '"' */
};
```

Here's the character drawing routine:

```
void drawchar(unsigned char c, int x, int y, int fgcolor)
{
    for (int yOffset = 0; yOffset < 4; yOffset++)
    {
        unsigned char bitshift0 = font[c][yOffset];
        unsigned char bitshift1 = font[c][yOffset] << 8;

        if (bit_check(bitshift0, 0)) {putpixel(x + 0, y + (yOffset), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift0, 1)) {putpixel(x + 1, y + (yOffset), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift0, 2)) {putpixel(x + 2, y + (yOffset), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift0, 3)) {putpixel(x + 3, y + (yOffset), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift0, 4)) {putpixel(x + 4, y + (yOffset), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift0, 5)) {putpixel(x + 5, y + (yOffset), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift0, 6)) {putpixel(x + 6, y + (yOffset), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift0, 7)) {putpixel(x + 7, y + (yOffset), fgcolor);}

        if (bit_check(bitshift1, 0)) {putpixel(x + 0, y + (yOffset * 2), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift1, 1)) {putpixel(x + 1, y + (yOffset * 2), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift1, 2)) {putpixel(x + 2, y + (yOffset * 2), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift1, 3)) {putpixel(x + 3, y + (yOffset * 2), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift1, 4)) {putpixel(x + 4, y + (yOffset * 2), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift1, 5)) {putpixel(x + 5, y + (yOffset * 2), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift1, 6)) {putpixel(x + 6, y + (yOffset * 2), fgcolor);}
        if (bit_check(bitshift1, 7)) {putpixel(x + 7, y + (yOffset * 2), fgcolor);}
    }
}
```

Here's the bit_check function:

```
bool bit_check(var,pos) {return !!((var) & (1 << (pos)));}
```

And here's the way I'm calling drawchar:

```
drawchar('!', 30, 20, 4);
```

This doesn't display anything at all. I have no clue why.

I've tried checking if there's any data being read whatsoever, and it looks like it's all 0's. I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: `bit_check(bitshift1, 0 to 7)` is alwasy 0 as `bitshift1 = font[c][yOffset] << 8` forms a lower byte of 8 zero bits.  Was this intended?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No, it wasn't. It checks the higher byte by shifting it over. I imagine I shifted the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed, `bitshift1` is shifted in the opposite way.
Would you please modify the `drawchar()` function as follows:

```
void drawchar(unsigned char c, int x, int y, int fgcolor)
{
    int xOffset, yOffset;
    unsigned char bitshift;

    // draw the upper half plane
    for (yOffset = 0; yOffset < 4; yOffset++) {
        bitshift = font[c][yOffset] >> 8;       // take higher 8 bits
        for (xOffset = 0; xOffset < 8; xOffset++) {
            if (bit_check(bitshift, xOffset)) {
                putpixel(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, fgcolor);
            }
        }
    }
    // draw the lower half plane
    for (yOffset = 4; yOffset < 8; yOffset++) {
        bitshift = font[c][yOffset - 4] && 0xff;// take lower 8 bits
        for (xOffset = 0; xOffset < 8; xOffset++) {
            if (bit_check(bitshift, xOffset)) {
                putpixel(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, fgcolor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the `putpixel()` function is not available to me, it includes assumptions
about the x-y coordinate direction. If the image is flipped (e.g. upside down)
please let me know.

**[Edit]**
Here is a test code. Please put the `drawchar_test()` function below instead of current `drawchar()` function. Then it will display lower half filled rectangle (regardless of the passed value of `c`).

```
void drawchar_test(unsigned char c, int x, int y, int fgcolor)
{
    int xOffset, yOffset;
    unsigned char bitshift;

    for (yOffset = 0; yOffset < 4; yOffset++) {
        bitshift = 0xff;
        for (xOffset = 0; xOffset < 8; xOffset++) {
            if (bitshift & 0x80) {
                putpixel(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, fgcolor);
            }
            bitshift <<= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

If it works, then please proceed to use the code below:

```
void drawchar(unsigned char c, int x, int y, int fgcolor)
{
    int xOffset, yOffset;
    unsigned char bitshift;

    // draw the upper half plane
    for (yOffset = 0; yOffset < 4; yOffset++) {
        bitshift = font[c][yOffset] >> 8;       // take higher 8 bits
        for (xOffset = 0; xOffset < 8; xOffset++) {
            if (bitshift & 0x80) {              // check the leftmost bit
                putpixel(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, fgcolor);
            }
            bitshift <<= 1;                     // shift to the left
        }
    }
    // draw the lower half plane
    for (yOffset = 4; yOffset < 8; yOffset++) {
        bitshift = font[c][yOffset - 4] & 0xff; // take lower 8 bits
        for (xOffset = 0; xOffset < 8; xOffset++) {
            if (bitshift & 0x80) {              // check the leftmost bit
                putpixel(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, fgcolor);
            }
            bitshift <<= 1;                     // shift to the left
        }
    }
}
```

The code above does not use the `bit_check()` function and it will run faster as a positive side effect.

**[Edit2]**
As a clue to debug, would you please test the following function:

```
void drawchar_test2(unsigned char c, int x, int y, int fgcolor)
{
    int xOffset, yOffset;
    unsigned char bitshift;
    int i;

    /* print the font values of '!' */
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("[%d] = %x\n", i, font[c][i]);
    }

    /* overwrites font values of '!' */
    font[c][0] = 0x18;
    font[c][1] = 0x1818;
    font[c][2] = 0x1800;
    font[c][3] = 0x1818;

    // draw the upper half plane
    for (yOffset = 0; yOffset < 4; yOffset++) {
        bitshift = font[c][yOffset] >> 8;       // take higher 8 bits
        for (xOffset = 0; xOffset < 8; xOffset++) {
            if (bitshift & 0x80) {              // check the leftmost bit
                putpixel(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, fgcolor);
            }
            bitshift <<= 1;                     // shift to the left
        }
    }
    // draw the lower half plane
    for (yOffset = 4; yOffset < 8; yOffset++) {
        bitshift = font[c][yOffset - 4] & 0xff; // take lower 8 bits
        for (xOffset = 0; xOffset < 8; xOffset++) {
            if (bitshift & 0x80) {              // check the leftmost bit
                putpixel(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, fgcolor);
            }
            bitshift <<= 1;                     // shift to the left
        }
    }
}
```

It checks two factors:

- The font table has proper values.
- The font is displayed if the font table has proper values.

If the printed values are incorrect while the font is properly displayed, please make sure the variable `font` is properly assigned and can be read.

Comment: Thanks! I don't like that it has has a lot of loops, though, as I was hoping to keep it reasonably fast to execute..

Comment: Oh, and I just tested it, it doesn't display anything. The character I tried to display is in my font array, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: In my test environment it sets pixels in the dummy array. Try to modify the `x` `y` position and / or `fgcolor` in `drawchar('!', 30, 20, 4)`.

Comment: As for the speed, the inner loop is no slower than your direct implementation changing the value from 0 to 7.

Comment: To begin with, have you already achieved to display any figures or lines using the `putpixel()` function?

Comment: The putpixel function does work. The fgcolor is the VGA palette index for red, and that works in a putpixel call. So does that x and y. I've tried to put it at 0, 0 but that didn't display anything either.

Comment: Thank you for the experiments and feedback. Going back to the yesterday's condition, you mentioned your posted code displays nothing. However, it *should* display the half plane which is not affected by the `shift` operation. I'll write some test code to find the cause of the problem or modify my code without using the `bit_check()` function. Please wait a while.

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional codes. Would you please test them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to my laptop with the data on it right now, so you'll have to wait for a bit (probably a few days)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. It doesn't matter at all. Please take your time and good luck.  Cheers.

Comment: I've just tested `drawchar_test` and it does display, but your modified `drawchar` function doesn't work. Could this be an issue with the font table instead of the function itself?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I agree with your opinion that the font table may have an issue. I've updated my answer with another test function in `Edit2`. Would you please try it?

Comment: Errm, `printf` doesn't work in my environment. This function _is_ the print function. The whole of the standard library isn't included either. (As that doesn't work in my environment either)

Comment: Okay. Isn't there any way to dump the variable values including the debugger? If any, please check the values of `font` with your appropriate way. If not, just remove the `printf()` lines of my code and just test the display.

Comment: There is no debugger, this is a bootstrapped kernel. (And no, I can't run it in an emulator. For some reason, when I run it in a emulator, it just crashes with a disk read error, but it works in a VM and real hardware) I've tested the display, this is what I got: https://imgur.com/IW1Zvb7

Comment: Thank you for the test. Now it is *mostly* evident the `font` array has
an issue. As I'm not seeing your whole code (including the main()), I cannot
identify which code has the problem. Please make sure the variable `font`
is declared/defined as a global variable and properly initialized.
If you are not sure, a possible workaround is to explicitly pass `font` as
another argument to the `drawchar()` function.

Comment: With the test code, the '!' character is displayed upside down.
Judging from the variable names such as `x` and `y`, I had assumed
the coordinate system has its origin at the lower left corner, but
it should be uppper left corner. I'll fix my code accordingly. Cheers.

Comment: The coordinate system (upside-down) fixed. Now it's your turn to solve the `font` issue. Good luck.